# I can't select mailbox for ImapClient (c#)

Tags: c#, email, imap

I need get letters from email. Those messages does not exist in the folder "Inbox", but they exist in the folder "All mail".

I use lib "S22.Imap". DefaultMailbox in this ImapClient is "INBOX". But if I change this DefaultMailbox I have an exception: "xm002 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: All mail(Failure)".

My code:

```
   ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993,
                "email", "password", AuthMethod.Login, true))

   Client.DefaultMailbox = "All mail";
   IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search((SearchCondition.All()));
   var messages = Client.GetMessages(uids);
```

Help me, please, with my problem!

Answer (score 3):

I understood. I need to write

```
Client.DefaultMailbox = "[Gmail]/All Mail";
```

instead

```
Client.DefaultMailbox = "All mail";
```

Comment: perfect answer you make my day